# Compare $SSreg (X_1,X_2)$ and $SSreg (X_1)+SSreg (X_2)$ with intuitive explanation for this relationship

Tags: regression, sums-of-squares

Please I need help from the experts regaring this question:
Regression with uncorrelated predictors: Suppose that we fit the following model: 
    [image]

Compare [image]. Give an intuitive explanation for this relationship.

Comment: Can you tell us what $SS_{reg} (X_1)$ and +$SS_{reg} R(X_2)$ mean, especially the $R$

Comment: @Henry Thanks for your efforts (Upvoted!). SS is sum of square. You can see the whole question here [link](https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/5-regression-uncorrelated-predictors-suppose-fit-following-model-predictors-satisfy-answer-q35804826)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the sketch. try to work out the technical details by yourself. Note/Show that for the simple (univariate) regression you have $SSreg(X_1) =\hat{\beta_1}^2\sum (X_{1i} - \bar{X}_{1n})^2 $, and that for the bivariate model you have 
$$
\bar{Y}_n = {\hat{\beta}_0} + {\hat{\beta}_1}\bar{X}_{1n} + {\hat{\beta}_0}\bar{X}_{2n},
$$
next plug it in the SSreg of the bivariate model
\begin{align}
SSreg(X_1, X_2) &= \sum( \hat{Y} - \bar{Y}_n) ^2\\
& = \sum ( {\hat{\beta}_0} + {\hat{\beta}_1}X_{1i} + {\hat{\beta}_0}X_{2i} 
-
{\hat{\beta}_0} - {\hat{\beta}_1}\bar{X}_{1n} - {\hat{\beta}_0}\bar{X}_{2n})^2\\
& = \sum (\hat{\beta}_1(X_{1i} - \bar{X}_{1n}) + \hat{\beta}_2(X_{1i} - \bar{X}_{2n}))\\
&= \hat{\beta_1}^2\sum (X_{1i} - \bar{X}_{1n})^2  + \hat{\beta_2}^2\sum (X_{2i} - \bar{X}_{2n})^2\\
& = SSreg(X_1) + SSreg(X_2),
\end{align} 
note that the middle term
$$
\hat{\beta}_1\hat{\beta}_2 \sum (X_{1i} - \bar{X}_{1n})(X_{2i} - \bar{X}_{2n}) = 0,
$$
because $X_1$ and $X_2$ are uncorrelated.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Appreciate your help (deseved upvoting !)